# ListView separator between items

Tags: .net, xaml, listview, uwp, list-separator

I would like to insert a separator between items in a `ListView`, like in the image below.

[image: Sample]

There are 2 problems:

1. If I add it (as a Border) at the bottom of the item in the `ItemTemplate`, the last item will have a separator, and it should not.
2. If I find a way to add a separator **outside the `ItemTemplate`**, how would I align it to the labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `DataTemplateSelector` for this. First you need to create Two `DataTemplate`'s

For example: In a simple ItemsControl which I want to show you a list of String, My Two `DataTemplate`'s would look like below.

```
<Page.Resources>  
    <DataTemplate x:Name="AllItems">  
        <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2">  
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ''}" Padding="10" Margin="10,0" />  
        </Border>  
    </DataTemplate>  
    <DataTemplate x:Name="LastItems">  
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ''}" Padding="10" Margin="10,0" />  
    </DataTemplate>  
</Page.Resources>
```

Now I create a `DataTemplateSelector` and Check if the Item that I need to apply the `DataTemplate` is Last one or not.

```
public class ItemsDataTemplateSelector: DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate AllItems { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate LastItems { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        DataTemplate _returnTemplate = new DataTemplate();
        var itemsControl = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(container);
        if (itemsControl.IndexFromContainer(container) == (itemsControl.ItemsSource as List<String>).Count-1)
        {
            _returnTemplate = LastItems;
        }
        else
        {
            _returnTemplate = AllItems;
        }
        return _returnTemplate;
    }
}
```

Now my `ItemsControl` Implementation would be

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="listView">  
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>  
        <local:ItemsDataTemplateSelector AllItems="{StaticResource AllItems}" LastItems="{StaticResource LastItems}" />  
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>  
</ItemsControl>
```

Here is how i set the ItemsSource to ItemsControl

```
List<String> items = new List<string>();  
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)  
{  
    items.Add("Item " + i.ToString());  
}  
listView.ItemsSource = items;
```

Below is your output. You can see Last Item does not have a `Border`

[image]

Comment: However, this is hardly reusable.

Answer (score -2):

Use Divider attribute in XML in listView.I hope it fulfills your requirment.For example,

In activity_main.xml:

```
    <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttn"
    android:divider="@color/Divider"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/listview"/>
```

In color.xml:

```
 <resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
<color name="Divider">#085411</color></resources>
```

Comment: The question is about UWP. Not Android